# Switch statement inside for loop does not increment "i" correctly

Tags: java, for-loop, switch-statement

I have the following code:

```
String everything = sb.toString(); //stores all the data from the input file into a string
String replaceAll = everything.replaceAll("\\s", "");
int charCount = replaceAll.length(); //charCount is 147
char arr[] = replaceAll.toCharArray();
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    switch (arr[i]) {
        case 'E': {
            fridge[Character.getNumericValue(arr[(i + 1)])].is_empty();
        }
        break;
        case 'F': {
            fridge[Character.getNumericValue(arr[(i + 2)])].find_it(Character.getNumericValue(arr[(i + 1)]));
        }
        break;
        case 'C': {
            fridge[Character.getNumericValue(arr[(i + 3)])].combineFridge(fridge[Character.getNumericValue(arr[(i + 2)])], fridge[Character
                                                                                                                                          .getNumericValue(arr[(i + 1)])]);
        }
        break;
        case 'M': {
            fridge[Character.getNumericValue(arr[(i + 3)])].commonItems(fridge[Character.getNumericValue(arr[(i + 2)])], fridge[Character
                                                                                                                                        .getNumericValue(arr[(i + 1)])]);
        }
        break;
        case 'I': {
            fridge[Character.getNumericValue(arr[(i + 2)])].insertItem(Character.getNumericValue((i + 1)));
        }
        break;
        case 'D': {
            fridge[Character.getNumericValue(arr[(i + 2)])].delete_item(Character.getNumericValue((i + 1)));
        }
        break;
        case 'O': {
            fridge[Character.getNumericValue(arr[(i + 1)])].outputRefrigerator();
        }
        break;

    }
}
```

The char array has 147 elements, and there's a number after each letter. 
Each letter activates a method, followed by 1-3 parameters (numbers).
However, inside the for loop, I am getting a -1 value and sometimes random large numbers (all my numbers are positive and less than 12).

If I manually call any method outside the for loop for example:
`fridge[Character.getNumericValue(arr[0].insertItem(Character.getNumericValue(arr[1]);`, everything works fine and the value which is at `arr[1]` (which is 1) is stored at `this.fridgeItems` (an int[] array).

Why is this happening? I know it's a problem with either the switch statement or the for loop but I can't really tell.

Comment: Suppose `arr[0]` is an opcode and `arr[1]` through `arr[3]` are its arguments. Do you expect `i` to jump from 0 straight to 4? You're only incrementing it by 1 every time.

Comment: There is no code *in the switch statement* to actually increment `i`.

Comment: What is the point of all those braces in the switch statement?

Comment: And why do you create the array arr ? Why not just `switch(replaceAll.charAt(i))` ?

Comment: Heaven help any poor soul who ever has to maintain this code.

Comment: *"all my numbers are positive and less than 12"* How does this statement apply to the code when you only use `getNumericValue()` of single characters? I mean, normally we'd understand single digits to be 0-9, so how you'd ever expect a number like 11 is beyond me, unless you include things like Unicode Roman Numerals (e.g. [`Ⅺ`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/216a/index.htm)). Is that what you are doing?

Answer (score 1):

Check your indices. In your code you are accessing elements from `arr` by `i + 1` and `i + 2` index. If your loop iterates more than `n - 2` times, you will have IndexOutOfBoundException.

By the way, you need to increment `i` in your switch statement to skip "used" characters from the input array.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is *"not increment `i` correctly"*, because there is no code in the switch statement to actually increment `i`.

You should do something like this:

```
case 'C':
    fridge[Character.getNumericValue(arr[i + 3])]
            .combineFridge(fridge[Character.getNumericValue(arr[i + 2])],
                           fridge[Character.getNumericValue(arr[i + 1])]);
    i += 3;
    break;
```

Comment: And before accessing arr[i+3] you should check to ensure that i+3 < arr.length.

Comment: @FredK Only required if you want a better error message for bad input. If you do, you should also check that `Character.getNumericValue()` doesn't return negative value, or a value that exceeds the size of `fridge`. It's entirely up to OP whether to improve error message.

Comment: @C.Suarez Ok, show us the value of `everything` (or `replaceAll`), thereby getting closer to creating [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and we may be able to help you. Alternatively, if you get an error, show it. --- When I say show us, I mean edit the question and add the information.